# C newbie can't find Syntax Error

Tags: c

I'm having trouble finding the error in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LOOP    0
#define ENDLOOP 1
main()
{
  int c, loop;
  loop = LOOP;
    while ((c = getchar()) loop != ENDLOOP) {
      if (c == 'e'|| c == 'E') {
        printf ("END LOOP\n");
        loop = ENDLOOP;
      }
      else if (c == 'c' || c == 'C')
        printf ("Cheese\n");
      else 
        printf ("Not Cheese\n");
    }
}
```

The terminal is giving me this error:

```
1-1.c: In function ‘main’:
1-1.c:8: error: syntax error before ‘loop’
1-1.c: At top level:
1-1.c:13: error: syntax error before ‘else’
```

Comment: Is this the beginnings of the upcoming Cheese Shop-game? Will there be a bozouki soundtrack? :)

Comment: Rewriting `(c = getchar())` as `(c = tolower(getchar()))` can simplify your logic (no more need to explicitly check for upper- and lower-case input).

Comment: May I suggest that you take out those #defines. They only add confusion. You will get used to Boolean means of zero an non-zero soon enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
((c = getchar()) loop != ENDLOOP)
```

Should be:

```
((c = getchar()) && loop != ENDLOOP)
```

I'd recommend writing it in a totally different way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while (c = getchar()) {
        if (c == 'e' || c == 'E') {
            printf ("END LOOP\n");
            break;
        }
        if (c == 'c' || c == 'C') {
            printf ("Cheese\n");
        } else {
            printf ("Not Cheese\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think this way has fewer chances to make errors. You might also want to consider using [`tolower`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/tolower/).

Comment: No, those aren't *unbalanced*, though they could be simplified.

Comment: Was unbalanced: fixed now. And simplified verision provided. I found it too confusing (hence my error initially).

Comment: Your clarification from your update is scarily similar to my own example. :)

Comment: @mctylr: Yep, when I first saw your comment I thought you were just making a small improvement to my code. But there are subtle differences in whitespace that show it's not a copy.

Comment: The test should probably be `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && loop != ENDLOOP)`.

Answer (score 4):

Are you perhaps missing an operator?

```
while ((c = getchar()) && loop != ENDLOOP) {
```

Comment: The test should probably be `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && loop != ENDLOOP)`.

Answer (score 3):

At least one error is that you're missing an operator here:

```
 while ((c = getchar()) loop != ENDLOOP)
```

I assume you mean "AND" and thus it should be:

```
 while ((c = getchar()) && loop != ENDLOOP)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the ugly `loop != ENDLOOP` conditional and simplify your program in the process.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int c;
   while (EOF != (c = getchar())) {
      if (c == 'e'|| c == 'E') {
         printf ("END LOOP\n");
         break;
      } else if (c == 'c' || c == 'C')
         printf ("Cheese\n");
      else 
         printf ("Not Cheese\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The `EOF` not equal comparison makes explicit how `getchar()` can terminate the while loop. Otherwise the `break` does if 'e' or 'E' are taken from stdin.

The int in front of main, and the `return 0` are to make it clean ANSI C, so basically stylistic, but good style.

Comment: I find the reversed condition in the while loop perverse (for all some books recommend it - I disagree with those books) - but you _are_ testing for EOF which none of the other solutions does, so +1.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int x,y,z;
int large();
int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&x,&y,&z);
    large();
    return 1;
}
int large()
{
    printf("large is %d\n",x);
}
{
    else if (y>x;&&y>z)
    {
    printf("%d the larger\n",y);
    }
    else
    {
    printf("%d larger is",x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanations and edit your post for more clarify. And why did you insert those two big headings?